# android custom component to layout

Tags: android, layout, custom-component

I would like to add my custom `ImageView` to the xml layout.

**main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.android.gag.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`TouchImageView`, as its name implies, `extends` the `ImageView` class.

`Main.java`

`touchImageView = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.Image1);`

**My app crashes. Logcat output:**

```
10-16 20:38:20.275: E/AndroidRuntime(11354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 20:38:20.275: E/AndroidRuntime(11354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.gag/com.android.gag.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.android.gag.TouchImageView
10-16 20:38:20.275: E/AndroidRuntime(11354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
idRuntime(11354): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.android.gag.TouchImageView
10-16 20:38:20.275: E/AndroidRuntime(11354):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:589)
10-16 20:38:20.275: E/AndroidRuntime(11354):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
```

Please, could anyone help me?
I am a beginner, so answers like '' [replace "class library" with "Android library project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868345/android-defining-custom-component-layouts-in-xml)'' are pointless because they are too vague and I don't know where to start and where to go.

**EDIT:** Link to my [TouchImageView class](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43107774/TouchImageView.java)

Comment: Could you show your implementation of TouchImageView, please.

Comment: That issue commonly happens when you override wrongly the methods for your ImageView.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43107774/TouchImageView.java

Comment: the class is from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images/7458910#7458910 so I think it should be alright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for your custom View class is missing two constructors.  From the [Android docs for the View class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

```
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML.

```
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style.

It's crashing because it can't find the constructor it needs, so it can't inflate the view.

Implement both of these constructors for your TouchImageView class and see if the problem goes away.